# Pure Javascript Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to Javascript and I want to make simple slider using JS only (No jQuery or other plugins).

[image]

As you see, I've one red box appear, under this there are 2 more boxs (green and blue). What I want is to navigate between them using next and prev buttons. The code should be dynamic so If I added more box it should work without any update to the code.

Please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fufc0Lsg/) fiddle.

```
<div class="content">
         <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box-item red"></div>
            <div class="box-item blue"></div>
            <div class="box-item green"></div>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
        <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
     </div>
```

What I'm thinking about is:
1- Count the number of elements that have the class name "box-item".
2- Select the element and edit it's CSS "transform" translate(x,y)".
3- Then the next element will be shown.

```
var numItems = document.querySelectorAll('.box-item').length;
```

The above JS code count the number of elements, I want something to help me control the boxs by next prev buttons. Any ideas to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: look out for setInterval and clearInterval methods of javascript.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I checked this solution and I want to control it using next and prev buttons only.

Comment: So what you've done so far is... nothing? If you're going to ask for someone to do the whole thing for you, it's no different from looking at the source code of a slider library.

Comment: @shadeed9 one of the best ways to learn is to read other people code.

Comment: You need to use getElementsByClassName to get element references and use those to set zIndex or display styles. The getElementsByClassName function returns an array of element references. This should be enough information to get you started with Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an object oriented approach for this problem. You can create a slider object with the relevant functions and attributes...

HTML elements has attributes(eg: class, id, value, style..). For this I used a custom attribute called `translateVal` for the elements that represent boxes. That attribute keeps a track of the current x value of css `translate()` of the element.

```js
Slider = {
 current : 0,
 boxes : document.getElementsByClassName("box-item"),
 boxWidth: 0,
 init : function(boxWidth){
  Slider.boxWidth = boxWidth;
  Slider.boxes[0].style.transform = "translate(0px, 0)";
  Slider.boxes[0].translateVal = 0;
  for (var i=1; i<Slider.boxes.length; i++) {
   Slider.boxes[i].style.transform = "translate("+(boxWidth)+"px, 0)";
   Slider.boxes[i].translateVal = boxWidth;
  }
 },
 move : function(direction){
  if (direction == "left" && Slider.current > 0){
   Slider.current--;
  } else if (direction == "right" && Slider.current < Slider.boxes.length-1){
   Slider.current++;
  }
  for (var i=0; i<Slider.boxes.length; i++) {
   var translateVal = Slider.boxWidth;
   if (i == Slider.current){
    translateVal = 0;
   } 
   Slider.boxes[i].style.transform = "translate("+(translateVal)+"px, 0)";
   Slider.boxes[i].translateVal = translateVal;
  }   
 }
}
    
window.onload = function(){Slider.init(350)};
```

```css
.content {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 120px auto 0 auto;
}
.content .boxes {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #666666;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content .boxes .box-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.content .boxes .red {
  background: red;
}
.content .boxes .blue {
  background: blue;
}
.content .boxes .green {
  background: green;
}
.content .next {
  float: right;
}
.content .prev {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="content">
 <div class="boxes">
  <div class="box-item red" translateVal=""></div>
  <div class="box-item blue" translateVal=""></div>
  <div class="box-item green" translateVal=""></div>
 </div>
 <a href="#" class="next" onclick="Slider.move('right')">next</a>
 <a href="#" class="prev" onclick="Slider.move('left')">prev</a>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use CSS3 and javascript just to add remove class.

So you have transitions and animations and you activate them through javasript.

in this way no plugin and fast slides.

If the hardware aceleration of CSS3 doesnt convince you, I recommend you to wrap it with jQuery, no need to suffer using vanilla js for such a task.

//--------EDIT---------------//

What I mean is that with vanilla javascript i guess the way to get the animations is through setIntervals, and incrementing the left of the 3 inline slides container. Maybe is a comment, but as I said is dont gwant to go through that pain, my answer was just pointing out that theres no need of plugins or libraries if you have CSS3.

**I noticed that CSS3 was the answer**, that is why I mentioned.

relevant code will be

```
document.getElementById('myId').setAttribute("class", "firstSlide");
```

then click and

```
document.getElementById('myId').setAttribute("class", "secondSlide");
```

or

```
document.getElementById('myId').setAttribute("class", "thirdSlide");

#myId {
  transtion: all 1s ease;
}
#myId.firstSlide {
  .translateX(0) // using mixin for the sake off the example
}
#myId.secondSlide {
  .translateX(100%) // i mean the css translate, dont make me put all the prefixes
}
#myId.thirdSlide {
  .translateX(200%) 
}
```

Of course you can after this make a javascript function that counts the slides > set the width of the moving container to n * 100 + '%' and moves around depending if forward or backwards adding or resting 100% to container translatex each time, container should be container in a 100% size with overflow hidden

//-----edit-----//

for automating it you can make a function that counts slides, adds to the container the correct width 100*slides.length, and  translates the index*100 + 100 the xtranslation, something like that, there are many ways to automate the tasks, that was just an example to demostrate the css setup, so basically you declare general css rules and for the specifics of a set of slides you add the style with js

Comment: This is more like a comment with a recommendation than actual answer.? Or can you clarify your answer with relevant vanilla js code? (No jquery) as the post author mentioned?

Comment: @MaunoV. ok got it, explained myself a little more

Comment: should I manually add to css every new slide, I want to add? Or is there more common solution?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var helpers = {};
        helpers.once = function (fn, context) { 
            var result;
            return function() { 
                if(fn) {
                    result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);
                    fn = null;
                }
                return result;
            };
        };
        helpers.isset = function () {
            var a = arguments, l = a.length, i = 0, undef;
            if (l === 0) {
                throw new Error('Empty isset');
            }
            while (i !== l) {
                if (a[i] === undef || a[i] === null) {
                    return false;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        };
        helpers.empty = function (mixed_var) {
            var undef, key, i, len;
            var emptyValues = [undef, null, false, 0, '', '0'];
            for (i = 0, len = emptyValues.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (mixed_var === emptyValues[i]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (typeof mixed_var === 'object') {
                for (key in mixed_var) {
                    return false;
                }   
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        helpers.returnStyle = function (el, styleProp) {
            var x = undefined;
            if (this.isset(el.currentStyle)) {
                x = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
            } else if (this.isset(window.getComputedStyle)) {
                x = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
            }
            if(this.empty(x)) {
                x = '0px';
            }
            return x;
        };
        helpers.resetSliders = function (sliders) {
            for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
                sliders[i].resetSlider();
            }
        };
        
        // int - id to apply, 
        // loop - loop or not, 
        // sliderIntervalTime - milisecconds between loops, 
        // divsNumberShow - number of divs inside container, 
        // infiniteLoops - loop infinitely or not 
        var jsSlider = function(id, loop, sliderIntervalTime, divsNumberShow, infiniteLoops) {
            var self = this;
            this.container = undefined;
            this.containerMarginRight = 0;
            this.containerMarginLeft = 0;
            this.containerPaddingRight = 0;
            this.containerPaddingLeft = 0;
            this.containerBorderLeftWidth = 0;
            this.containerBorderRightWidth = 0;
            this.sliderInterval = undefined;
            this.tr = undefined;
            this.divs = undefined;
            this.numCallsInteval = 0;
            this.infiniteLoops = 0;
            this.loop = 0;
            this.containerWidth = 0;
            this.containerInner = 0;
            this.sliderIntervalTime = 4000;
            this.deviation = 0;
            this.divsNumberShow = 1;
            this.divsMarginRight = 0;
            this.divsMarginLeft = 0;
            this.divsPaddingRight = 0;
            this.divsPaddingLeft = 0;
            this.divsBorderLeftWidth = 0;
            this.divsBorderRightWidth = 0;
            this.pager = undefined;
            this.pagerCounter = 0;
            this.hideNext = function () {
                self.showNextPrev();
                var ctrlSelectors = self.container.getElementsByClassName("ctrl-selector");
                ctrlSelectors[1].style.display = 'none';
            };
            this.hidePrev = function () {
                self.showNextPrev();
                var ctrlSelectors = self.container.getElementsByClassName("ctrl-selector");
                ctrlSelectors[0].style.display = 'none';
            };
            this.showNextPrev = function () {
                var ctrlSelectors = self.container.getElementsByClassName("ctrl-selector");
                for (var i = 0; i < ctrlSelectors.length; i++) {
                    ctrlSelectors[i].style.display = 'block';
                }
            };
            this.showHideNextPrev = function () {
                var currentPagerLength = ((Math.ceil(self.divs.length / self.divsNumberShow)) - 1);
                if(!self.loop && (self.pagerCounter === currentPagerLength)) {
                    self.hideNext();
                } else if(!self.loop && self.pagerCounter === 0) {
                    self.hidePrev();
                } else {
                    self.showNextPrev();
                }
            };
            this.pagerReset = function () {
                var pagerElements = self.pager.getElementsByClassName("pager-element");
                for (var i = 0; i < pagerElements.length; i++) {
                    if(pagerElements[i].className === 'pager-element activated') {
                        pagerElements[i].className = 'pager-element';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                pagerElements[0].className += ' activated';
            };
            this.pagerMove = function () {
                var pagerElements = self.pager.getElementsByClassName("pager-element");
                var activatedElement = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < pagerElements.length; i++) {
                    if(pagerElements[i].className === 'pager-element activated') {
                        pagerElements[i].className = 'pager-element';
                        activatedElement = self.pagerCounter;
                    }
                }
                var activatedCounter = activatedElement < 0 ? pagerElements.length - 1 : activatedElement % pagerElements.length;
                pagerElements[activatedCounter].className = 'pager-element activated';
            };
            this.showPagerSlide = function (counter) {
                var currentPagerLength = ((Math.ceil(self.divs.length / self.divsNumberShow)) - 1);
                self.pagerCounter = (counter < 0 ? currentPagerLength : (counter > currentPagerLength ? 0 : counter));
                self.showHideNextPrev();
                for (var i = 0; i < self.divs.length; i++) {
                    if(self.loop && self.pagerCounter === 0) {
                        self.divs[i].style.right = '0px';
                    } else if(self.loop && self.pagerCounter === (self.divs.length - 1)) {
                        self.divs[i].style.right = (currentPagerLength * (self.containerInner)) + 'px';
                    } else {
                        self.divs[i].style.right = (self.pagerCounter * self.containerInner) + 'px';
                    }
                }
                self.pagerMove();
            };
            this.showPagerSlideStopInterval = function (counter) {
                self.showPagerSlide(counter);
                self.stopSlider();
            };
            this.showNextSlide = function () {
                self.pagerCounter++;
                self.showPagerSlide(self.pagerCounter);
            };
            this.showNextSlideStopInterval = function () {
                self.showNextSlide();
                self.stopSlider();
            };
            this.showPrevSlide = function () {
                self.pagerCounter--;
                self.showPagerSlide(self.pagerCounter);
            };
            this.showPrevSlideStopInterval = function () {
                self.showPrevSlide();
                self.stopSlider();
            };
            this.stopSlider = helpers.once(function() {
                clearInterval(self.sliderInterval);
            });
            this.startSlider = function () {
                if(self.numCallsInteval > 0) {
                    self.showNextSlide();
                }
                else {
                    self.stopSlider();
                }
                if(!self.infiniteLoops) {
                    self.numCallsInteval--;
                }
            };
            this.resetSlider = function () {
                if(self.loop) {
                    self.stopSlider();
                } else {
                    self.hidePrev();
                }
                self.recalcConainer();
                self.recalcDeviation();
                for (var i = 0; i < self.divs.length; i++) {
                    self.divs[i].style.width = ((self.containerInner - self.deviation) / self.divsNumberShow) + 'px';
                    self.divs[i].style.right =  '0px';
                }
                self.pagerReset();
            };
            this.recalcConainer = function () {
                self.containerMarginRight = helpers.returnStyle(self.container, 'margin-right');
                self.containerMarginLeft = helpers.returnStyle(self.container, 'margin-left');
                self.containerPaddingRight = helpers.returnStyle(self.container, 'padding-right');
                self.containerPaddingLeft = helpers.returnStyle(self.container, 'padding-left');
                self.containerBorderLeftWidth = helpers.returnStyle(self.container, 'border-left-width');
                self.containerBorderRightWidth = helpers.returnStyle(self.container, 'border-right-width');
                self.containerWidth = self.container.offsetWidth;
                
                self.containerInner = 
                    self.containerWidth 
                    - parseInt(self.containerPaddingRight) 
                    - parseInt(self.containerPaddingLeft) 
                    - parseInt(self.containerBorderLeftWidth) 
                    - parseInt(self.containerBorderRightWidth);
            };
            this.recalcDeviation = function () {
                self.deviation = 
                    (parseInt(self.divsMarginRight)
                    + parseInt(self.divsMarginLeft)
                    + parseInt(self.divsPaddingRight)
                    + parseInt(self.divsPaddingLeft)
                    + parseInt(self.divsBorderLeftWidth)
                    + parseInt(self.divsBorderRightWidth)) * self.divsNumberShow;
            };
            this.createSlider = function (id, loop, sliderIntervalTime, divsNumberShow, infiniteLoops) {
                if(helpers.isset(id)) {
                    self.loop = helpers.isset(loop) ? loop : 1;  
                    self.sliderIntervalTime = helpers.isset(sliderIntervalTime) ? sliderIntervalTime : 4000;
                    self.divsNumberShow = helpers.isset(divsNumberShow) ? divsNumberShow : 1;
                    self.container = document.getElementById(id);
                    var ctrlSelectorNext = document.createElement('span');
                    ctrlSelectorNext.id = 'next';
                    ctrlSelectorNext.className = 'ctrl-selector';
                    ctrlSelectorNext.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
                    ctrlSelectorNext.onclick = self.showNextSlideStopInterval;
                    self.container.appendChild(ctrlSelectorNext);
                    var ctrlSelectorPrev = document.createElement('span');
                    ctrlSelectorPrev.id = 'prev';
                    ctrlSelectorPrev.className = 'ctrl-selector';
                    ctrlSelectorPrev.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
                    ctrlSelectorPrev.onclick = self.showPrevSlideStopInterval;
                    self.container.insertBefore(ctrlSelectorPrev ,self.container.firstChild);
                    self.pager = document.createElement('div');
                    self.pager.className = 'pager';
                    self.container.appendChild(self.pager);
                    self.divs = self.container.getElementsByClassName("element");
                    self.divsMarginRight = helpers.returnStyle(self.divs[0], 'margin-right');
                    self.divsMarginLeft = helpers.returnStyle(self.divs[0], 'margin-left');
                    self.divsPaddingRight = helpers.returnStyle(self.divs[0], 'padding-right');
                    self.divsPaddingLeft = helpers.returnStyle(self.divs[0], 'padding-left');
                    self.divsBorderLeftWidth = helpers.returnStyle(self.divs[0], 'border-left-width');
                    self.divsBorderRightWidth = helpers.returnStyle(self.divs[0], 'border-right-width');
                    self.infiniteLoops = helpers.isset(infiniteLoops) ? infiniteLoops : 0;
                    self.recalcConainer();
                    self.recalcDeviation();
                    for (var i = 0; i < self.divs.length; i++) {
                        self.divs[i].style.width = ((self.containerInner - self.deviation) / self.divsNumberShow) + 'px';
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(self.divs.length / self.divsNumberShow); i++) {
                        var pagerElement = document.createElement('span');
                        pagerElement.className = 'pager-element';
                        pagerElement.innerHTML = i + 1;
                        if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function'){
                            (function (_i) {
                                pagerElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                    self.showPagerSlideStopInterval(_i);
                                });
                            })(i);
                        }
                        self.pager.appendChild(pagerElement);
                    }
                    self.numCallsInteval = Math.ceil(self.divs.length / self.divsNumberShow) - 1;
                    if(self.loop) {
                        self.sliderInterval = setInterval(function() {
                            self.startSlider();
                        }, self.sliderIntervalTime);
                    } else {
                        self.hidePrev();
                    }
                    self.pagerReset();
                }
            };
            this.createSlider(id, loop, sliderIntervalTime, divsNumberShow, infiniteLoops);
        };
        
        var sliders = [];
        var resizing;
        
        document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            sliders.push(new jsSlider("sa1", 1, 4000, 1, 0));
            sliders.push(new jsSlider("sa2", 1, 4000, 2, 1));
            sliders.push(new jsSlider("sa3", 1, 4000, 3, 0));
            sliders.push(new jsSlider("sm1", 0, 4000, 1));
            sliders.push(new jsSlider("sm2", 0, 4000, 2));
            sliders.push(new jsSlider("sm3", 0, 4000, 3));
        }, false );
        
        window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            clearTimeout(resizing);
            resizing = setTimeout(function () {
                helpers.resetSliders(sliders);}, 100);
        }, false );
```

```css
img {
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center
}
.quantum-slider {
 border:solid #aaa;
 border-width:1px;
 border-radius:5px; 
 width:auto; 
 margin:14px 10px; 
 color:#555; 
 font-size:1em; 
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 24px 10px;
}
.quantum-slider .element {
 position:relative;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 margin: 0 24px;
 padding: 0 5px;
 right:0;
 width: auto;
 white-space: normal;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.quantum-slider .lena {
 border: 1px solid #aaa; 
 padding: 10px 0;
}
.quantum-slider span {
 cursor:pointer;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 width:24px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color:#eee;
}
.quantum-slider span:hover {
 background-color:#ddd;
}
.quantum-slider span:active {
 background-color:#ccc;
}
.quantum-slider span#prev {
 background-image:url("http://www.ciaomondo.it/code/quanton-pure-js-slider/arrow-left.png");
 background-position:50% 50%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:24px auto;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 z-index:101;
}
.quantum-slider span#next {
 background-image:url("http://www.ciaomondo.it/code/quanton-pure-js-slider/arrow-right.png");
 background-position:50% 50%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:24px auto;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 z-index:101;
}

.pager {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10px 0 -10px 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.pager span {
 width: 1em;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 1em;
 padding: 0.2em;
 border-radius: 25%;
}

.pager span.activated{
 background-color:#ddd;
 cursor:default;
}
```

```html
<h1>Javascript pure div slider (No jQuery)</h1>
<p>
 You can apply every style you want to the slider container and the slider can contain only divs.<br> 
 You must apply to all the element divs inside the slider the same style for the slider to work correctly.<br>
 The elements divs inside the slider will adapt based on the style you apply.<br> 
 If something visual is wrong with the slider when you put it inside the html pages written by you, verify if there are conflicts between the slider styles and your styles.
</p>
<h2>Slider with auto scrolling</h2>
<h3>Slider with only 1 visible div, scrolls till last div</h3>
<div id="sa1" class="quantum-slider"><!-- 
 --><div class="element">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare lacinia ligula vel vehicula. Phasellus.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--                                                         
 --><div class="element">3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor suscipit enim, eu bibendum leo. Praesent sit amet lectus vitae dolor ornare dictum. Pellentesque accumsan, urna in facilisis tincidunt, felis diam euismod augue, ac mollis tortor nibh quis diam. Duis semper tincidunt aliquam. Nam malesuada.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor suscipit enim, eu bibendum leo. Praesent sit amet lectus vitae dolor ornare dictum. Pellentesque accumsan, urna in facilisis tincidunt, felis diam euismod augue, ac mollis tortor nibh quis diam. Duis semper tincidunt aliquam. Nam malesuada.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--
--></div>
<h3>Slider with 2 visible divs, scrolls infinitely</h3>
<div id="sa2" class="quantum-slider"><!-- 
 --><div class="element lena">1. <img src="http://www.ciaomondo.it/code/quanton-pure-js-slider/adele.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></div><!--
 --><div class="element lena">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--                                                         
 --><div class="element lena">3. <img src="http://www.ciaomondo.it/code/quanton-pure-js-slider/adele.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></div><!--
 --><div class="element lena">4. <img src="http://www.ciaomondo.it/code/quanton-pure-js-slider/adele.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></div><!--
 --><div class="element lena">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
--></div>
<h3>Slider with 3 visible divs, scrolls till last div</h3>
<div id="sa3" class="quantum-slider"><!-- 
 --><div class="element">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare lacinia ligula vel vehicula. Phasellus.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--                                                         
 --><div class="element">3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor suscipit enim, eu bibendum leo. Praesent sit amet lectus vitae dolor ornare dictum. Pellentesque accumsan, urna in facilisis tincidunt, felis diam euismod augue, ac mollis tortor nibh quis diam. Duis semper tincidunt aliquam. Nam malesuada.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">7. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
--></div>
<h2>Slider with manual scrolling</h2>
<h3>Slider with only 1 visible div</h3>
<div id="sm1" class="quantum-slider"><!-- 
 --><div class="element">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare lacinia ligula vel vehicula. Phasellus.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--                                                         
 --><div class="element">3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor suscipit enim, eu bibendum leo. Praesent sit amet lectus vitae dolor ornare dictum. Pellentesque accumsan, urna in facilisis tincidunt, felis diam euismod augue, ac mollis tortor nibh quis diam. Duis semper tincidunt aliquam. Nam malesuada.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--
--></div>
<h3>Slider with 2 visible divs</h3>
<div id="sm2" class="quantum-slider"><!-- 
 --><div class="element">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare lacinia ligula vel vehicula. Phasellus.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--                                                         
 --><div class="element">3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor suscipit enim, eu bibendum leo. Praesent sit amet lectus vitae dolor ornare dictum. Pellentesque accumsan, urna in facilisis tincidunt, felis diam euismod augue, ac mollis tortor nibh quis diam. Duis semper tincidunt aliquam. Nam malesuada.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
--></div>
<h3>Slider with 3 visible div</h3>
<div id="sm3" class="quantum-slider"><!-- 
 --><div class="element">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare lacinia ligula vel vehicula. Phasellus.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--                                                         
 --><div class="element">3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor suscipit enim, eu bibendum leo. Praesent sit amet lectus vitae dolor ornare dictum. Pellentesque accumsan, urna in facilisis tincidunt, felis diam euismod augue, ac mollis tortor nibh quis diam. Duis semper tincidunt aliquam. Nam malesuada.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis id velit sed accumsan. Mauris sodales eros nec justo semper sagittis. Praesent nisl mauris, lacinia ac laoreet quis, posuere sed enim. Vestibulum quis congue nisl.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--
 --><div class="element">7. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel blandit nisi. Sed id magna mattis dolor convallis vulputate. Aenean justo leo, laoreet id est.</div><!--
--></div>
```

Here you can find a very customizable pure javascript div slider.

https://github.com/quanton81/quanton-pure-js-slider

The script has a lot of options.

1. It works with divs.
2. It can be used with all the divs you want.
3. It can be set an inital visibility for n - divs, the others are scrollable.
4. The divs can scroll automatically or manually.
5. The divs can scroll till the last div and then stop or scroll infinitely.
6. There can be multiple sliders on the same page with combined options per slider